# How to update button in UITableViewRowAction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableviewrowaction

I use objective-c programming iPhone App. version is after iOS 8.1. there are some UITableViewRowAction in my UITableViewCell, i post request after tapping one of UITableViewRowAction, if successful, i want update the button (UITableViewRowAction) to be invalid so that it can not be tapped again. please help me, it is important ,but i have no solution.

as shown in figure:
this is the cell we can swipe left

[image]

we can see the three buttons after swiping left

[image]

Comment: You need to maintain a state manually for every cell.
Save the value if user clicks on your action button.
When user swipes the cell again simply change background color of that button and do not write action block for that.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are need to use UITableView delegate method

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: the button is not added by UITableViewCell, which is added as UITableViewRowAction, you will see it after slide Cell left

Answer (score 0):

Use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to post your request.

In your implementation:

```
{
int selectedIndex;
}
```

Then:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
       selectedIndex=indexPath.row;

        YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndex];
        if(cell.cellEnabled)
        {
        //Your request goes here...
        }
        else
       {
      //The cell is disabled..
        }
  }
```

cellEnabled is a BOOL value declared inside your cell.h file that you have to set to "YES" on successful response of the request.

ie; on getting success response, add the following code

```
YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndex];
cell.cellEnabled=YES;
```

Comment: I do not want make UITableViewCell invalid, i just want to make button(UITableViewRowAction) invalid

Comment: which button are you talking about?Is it inside the cell?If so ,on getting the success response,add the following code. YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndex];cell.button.enabled=NO;

Comment: upload an image if possible.

Comment: I have added two images, the buttons in right are my target

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views